# Morphism of 2-sites

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, sites

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Grothendieck sites. A $\textit{morphism}$ between $X$ and $Y$ is a functor on the underlying categories that is covering-flat and preserves covering families. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/morphism+of+sites for details.

There is also the notion of a 2-site (https://ncatlab.org/michaelshulman/show/2-site)

What is a morphism of 2-sites? I haven't found any literature on the topic.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing any definition of this in the literature.  It shouldn't hard to write down a definition by analogy with the 1-categorical case, though.